# Whats the proper way of including js/css with ajaxed html partials?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm building my first ajax-heavy application and am not sure of the proper approach for such things.

If, for example I ajax in a html partial (a form), with:

```
$('#content').load('form.html');
```

**how should I include the javascript and css?**

I can, of course include them in the original document, but that seems wasteful if the form is never loaded.  I can inline them (in form.html) with `<script>` and `<style>` elements, but that seems like the wrong approach.

Comment: curious why this was voted as "not constructive".  Seems to me it could be a useful question.  However, I suppose it *is* more of a "discussion" question than one with a canonical answer - maybe there is a way I should reword it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a separate JS file and load it using [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) in the `.load` callback.

Inline CSS should work fine, but since you run the risk of it messing up your main page, you should load it as part of the main page and not with AJAX.

If it were me, though, I wouldn't be afraid to leave a few extra lines of well-targeted JS *and* CSS code in your main page -- it's more efficient to load it with the other JS and CSS at the beginning, in the same file(s), than to fire off another network connection and wait for it to download.

Comment: Are there benefits to not inlining the js other than seperation of concerns?  It may only be a half-dozen lines of JS (maybe 2-3x that of CSS), and I want to stay performance-minded.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "inlining", but it's always a good idea to put ALL of your CSS and JS in separate external files. That way, if you're making edits later, you don't have to go hunting through your HTML for inlined code. That said, if it's just one short JS function or a couple of CSS classes relevant to just one page, I'll usually put them in the `<head>` instead of externalizing them.

Comment: Also, in this specific example, the form will be js dependant, so perhaps I should reverse the order: call `.load('form...` with `getScript()` as the callback?

Comment: You need to show specific code for me to be able to answer that.

Comment: no `<head>` in *form.html*... just a html partial. I think I will just use `<style>` and `<script>` elements for now however, unless it becomes significantly larger than it is now, at which point I'll externalize them for greater maintainability.  There's no X-browser or other issues with having `<style>` and `<script>` elements loaded into the middle of the `<body>` is there?

Comment: No, it's just bad form because they're harder to find if you're editing. As a matter of good style, you should put all your CSS in the `<head>` or an external file, and all your JS in the `<head>` or after the `<body>` with or without external files.

Comment: agreed, but with this ajaxy stuff it gets a bit more complicated huh? - the `load`ed file doesn't have access to the original page - its just a chunk of html loaded into a `div`

Comment: You're probably overcomplicating things, but since you haven't posted much actual code, **I can't tell.** You're asking for concrete solutions to abstract problems. Please come back and post a new question when you have a specific problem to solve.

Comment: Of course the loaded file gets access to the js and css files used in original file i.e. if the file is loaded in a div in original file.

Comment: Thanks @Blazemonger - I'm specifically keeping it abstract since I'm still in the early stages of what may very well become a large application, and while my example here is somewhat specific, I'm trying to get a feel for what things I should be considering moving forward - and this discussion has helped quite a bit.

Comment: If the only problem with inlined JS/CSS is that now your code is all over the place, then you should embed it by calling an embedded server side function. Then, it's defined in one place.

Comment: @bart Not any kind of improvement from the developer's POV. I direct interested parties to [this man's](http://javascript.crockford.com/) books and articles to avoid further pointless debate about established good practices.

Answer (score 2):

The $.getScript() would make an additional http request to load the js file that is to be used in form.html.

So, say for example, if you load 20 forms via ajax, you  have to make 20+20 http request( 20 for loading js file and 20 for loading the html for forms)

A possible optimized approach is:

loading the all the css ( minified) at the beginning.

IF a single js file is real large even after minifying,

Arrange the js functionality based on the PROABABILITY of use in different files ( (the fewer number of files , the better).

Minify those files and load the file with highest probability at the beginning .

And then use $.getScript() to load the file after checking if the file has already been loaded.

Comment: thanks for the additional perf. info.  Nothing I wasn't aware of, but may be of use to future users.  Your last couple sentences are still a bit unclear though...

Comment: You can check if the js function you are going to need is already loaded ( can be done using: if[jQuery.isFunction(Your_Functoion_Name))], if not then load the required file. This way you would be able to avoid making more than one loading of the same js file.